# Python Gevent Shared Queue (Listener Process)

Tags: python, logging, queue, gevent

I am trying to get some code working where I can implement logging into a multi-threaded program using gevent. What I'd like to do is set up custom logging handlers to put log events into a Queue, while a listener process is continuously watching for new log events to handle appropriately. I have done this in the past with Multiprocessing, but never with Gevent.

I'm having an issue where the program is getting caught up in the infinite loop (listener process), and not allowing the other threads to "do work"...

Ideally, after the worker processes have finished, I can pass an arbitrary value to the listener process to tell it to break the loop, and then join all the processes together. Here's what I have so far:

```
import gevent
from gevent.pool import Pool
import Queue
import random
import time

def listener(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            num = q.get()
            print "The number is: %s" % num
            if num <= 100:
                print q.get()
            # got passed 101, break out
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue
def worker(pid,q):
    if pid == 0:
        listener(q)
    else:
        gevent.sleep(random.randint(0,2)*0.001)
        num = random.randint(1,100)
        q.put(num)

def main():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    all_threads = []
    all_threads = [gevent.spawn(worker, pid,q) for pid in xrange(10)]
    gevent.wait(all_threads[1:])
    q.put(101)
    gevent.joinall(all_threads)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As I said, the program seems to be getting hung up on that first process and does not allow the other workers to do their thing. I have also tried spawning the listener process completely separately itself (which is actually how I would rather do it), but that didn't seem to work either so I tried this way.

Any help would be appreciated, feel like I am probably just missing something obvious about gevent's back end.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that your listener is never yielding if the queue is initially empty.  The first task you spawn is your listener.  When it starts, there's a `while True:`, the q will be empty, so you go to the else branch, which just continues, looping back to the start of the while loop, and then the q is still empty.  So you just sit in the first thread constantly checking the q is empty.

The key thing here is that gevent does not use "native" threads or processes.  Unlike "real" threads, which can be switched to at any time by something behind the scenes (like your OS scheduler), gevent uses 'greenlets', which require that you do something to "yield control" to another task.  That something is whatever gevent thinks would block, such as read from the network, disk, or use one of the blocking gevent operations.

One crude fix would be to start your listener when `pid == 9` rather than 0.  By making it spawn last, there will be items in the q, and it will go into the main if branch.   The downside is that this doesn't fix the logic problem, so the first time the queue is empty, you'll get stuck in your infinite loop again.

A more correct fix would be to put `gevent.sleep()` instead of `continue`.  sleep is a blocking operation, so your other tasks will get a chance to run.  Without arguments, it waits for no time, but still gives gevent the chance to decide to switch to another task if it is ready to run.   This still isn't very efficient, though, as if the Queue is empty, it's going to spend a lot of pointless time checking that over and over and asking to run again as soon as it can.  sleep'ing for longer than the default of 0 will be more efficient, but would delay processing your log messages.

However, you can instead take advantage of the fact that many of gevent's types, such as Queue, can be used in more Pythonic ways and make your code a lot simpler and easier to understand, as well as more efficient.

```
import gevent
from gevent.queue import Queue

def listener(q):
    for msg in q:
        print "the number is %d" % msg

def worker(pid,q):
    gevent.sleep(random.randint(0,2)*0.001)
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    q.put(num)

def main():
    q = Queue()
    listener_task = gevent.spawn(listener, q)
    worker_tasks = [gevent.spawn(worker, pid, q) for pid in xrange(1, 10)]
    gevent.wait(worker_tasks)
    q.put(StopIteration)
    gevent.join(listener_task)
```

Here, `Queue` can operate as an iterator in a `for` loop.  As long as there are messages, it will get an item, run the loop, and then wait for another item.  If there are no items, it will just block and hang around until the next one arrives.   Since it blocks, though, gevent will switch to one of your other tasks to run, avoiding the infinite loop problem your example code has.

Because this version is using the `Queue` as a for loop iterator, there's also automatically a nice sentinel value we can put in the queue to make the listener task quit.  If a for loop gets `StopIteration` from its iterator, it will exit cleanly.  So when our for loop that's reading from q gets `StopIteration` from the q, it exits, and then the function exits, and the spawned task is finished.